# Converting Excel table to Json format using VBA code causes unwanted format change of the Time column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert an Excel table to JSON format and store this value in an Excel sheet cell. The Excel Sheet layout is shown in the attached picture.

[image: Excel Sheet Layout]

The Json format you see in cell D14, which is based on the table range (A1:C3), is done using the "ExcelToJSON" function code that I have depicted below:

```vb
Public Function ExcelToJSON(rng As Range) As String
    ' Check there must be at least two columns in the Excel file
    If rng.Columns.Count < 2 Then
        ExcelToJSON = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    
    Dim dataLoop, headerLoop As Long
    ' Get the first row of the Excel file as a header
    Dim headerRange As Range: Set headerRange = Range(rng.Rows(1).Address)
    ' Count the number of columns of targeted Excel file
    Dim colCount As Long: colCount = headerRange.Columns.Count
    Dim JSON As String: JSON = " ""ItemList"":[   "
    For dataLoop = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        ' Skip the first row of the Excel file because it is used as header
        If dataLoop > 1 Then
            ' Start data row
            Dim jsonData As String: jsonData = "{"
            ' Loop through each column and combine with the header
            For headerLoop = 1 To colCount
                jsonData = jsonData & """" & headerRange.Value2(1, headerLoop) & """" & ":"
                jsonData = jsonData & """" & rng.Value2(dataLoop, headerLoop) & """"
                jsonData = jsonData & ","
            Next headerLoop
            ' Strip out the comma in last value of each row
            jsonData = Left(jsonData, Len(jsonData) - 1)
            ' End data row
            JSON = JSON & jsonData & "},"
        End If
    Next
    ' Strip out the last comma in last row of the Excel data
    JSON = Left(JSON, Len(JSON) - 1)
    JSON = JSON & "]"
    ExcelToJSON = JSON
End Function
```

This code nearly works perfectly, however, the issue I am having is that the JSON you see in cell D14 is changing the "Date" value to the 'General' excel format. How do I keep the time format for the date value from changing to 45130 45131, could you please help me with the code. Thanks!

Comment: Use `Format()` to create the date string format you want, or use the cell's `Text` property. .  You'll need to tell your code which table column(s) are dates, or check the header for "Date"

Comment: The `Value2` property returns the actual underlying value of the cell, regardless of its formatting or formula errors. As Tim's comment, `Text` is the best choice in your case.  `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value2?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461`

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I tried to use Text instead of Value2, but I get the #VALUE! error in D14 now.

Comment: Read the cell content one-by-one, not as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this issue, you need to format the date values explicitly as strings in the desired format.

```
For headerLoop = 1 To colCount
    jsonData = jsonData & """" & headerRange.Value2(1, headerLoop) & """" & ":"
    
    ' Check if the value is a date, and format it accordingly
    If IsDate(rng.Value2(dataLoop, headerLoop)) Then
        jsonData = jsonData & """" & Format(rng.Value2(dataLoop, headerLoop), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & """"
    Else
        jsonData = jsonData & """" & rng.Value2(dataLoop, headerLoop) & """"
    End If
    
    jsonData = jsonData & ","
Next headerLoop
```

Answer (score 0):

In Cell `B2` and `B3`, use the `=Text(value,"dd-mm-yyyy")` formula